# Send a mail from Django via Amazon SES

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to send a mail from my django app via Amazon SES but I keep getting the following error:

> smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (501, b'Invalid MAIL FROM address
>   provided', '=?utf-8?q?AKIAWMDVL5UEWNT3ODOO?=')

These are the settings that I am using:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'smtp credential key'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'smtp credential password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

and here's the code:

```
class CompanyCreateAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    def post(self, request):
        email = request.data["company_email"]
        phone = request.data["company_phone"]

        def random_with_N_digits(n):
            range_start = 10 ** (n - 1)
            range_end = (10 ** n) - 1
            return randint(range_start, range_end)

        code = random_with_N_digits(4)

        subject = 'Comapny Creation'
        message = 'Company Code is {}'.format(code)
        email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        recipient_list = [str(email), ]
        send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
```

I tried changing the port but it doesn't work, I have verified the email address in SES.. What is it that I am missing ?

Comment: Can you check, what is the value in email_from?
Error says that email_from is not a valid email, So first thing is to check that.

Comment: @OsamaKhalid I did and it was referring to `EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'smtp credential key'` in the settings, now I changed it to my verified email address but it still gives the `smtplib.SMTPDataError: (554, b'Message rejected: Email address is not verified` error

Comment: Yes, i think you should check again the address is verified or not, try send the verification email again. Or may be a simple spellcheck. 
As the error message clearly indicates that it is not verified.

Comment: Both the email address i.e To and From are verified

Comment: No worries. Can you show me EMAIL_HOST_USER and address list too. Where it says it verified?

Comment: Why not Boto (AWS SDK for Python) ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not want to use the SMTP credentials username as the "email from" value. That should be something human readable, whatever you want your recipients to see as the address where the email came from. That address and/or domain also need to be whitelisted in the SES settings.

In Django's `settings.py`, set the [`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL) setting to that address:

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'info@example.com'
```

Do not pass `email_from` as an explicit setting to `send_mail`, unless you want to override it for specific emails (e.g. send from `info@...` for certain emails and `newsletter@...` for other kinds of emails).